# Corporate data on internet

Tags: c#, .net, security, web-applications

Our corporate project is expanding. Among other requirements there's one that users from different (not trusted) forests should gain access. Older version of the application spanned only over our forest. Initially it was implemented as a Sharepoint intranet application.

And now I wonder could internet application be considrered as an option? I don't know whether it is a good idea to put corporate data on internet? Can it be secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't 100% secure anything on the web. Sure, you can implement SSL and various techniques to make it a little bit harder, however hackers can get into bank accounts, can infiltrate large beasts like Playstation network, Steam network etc., so I highly doubt you would do any better than them.

If you put something on the web, you must be prepared for the scenario, that at some point your data may be stolen. If you have critical data in there, which you really don't want to share with others, it's probably the best to keep them local. If you have some data that you want to share, put those on the web. But I'd opt against putting everything on the internet, that's a pure suicide.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Virtual Private Network (VPN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to access the intranet application from outside the company network.